# Why am I getting a compile error in a new installation?

Tags: compilation, version

Brand new Windows 10 Pro system running 1809. Just installed Access via Office 365 (version 1904). We have a database that was originally created in 1998 and has been updated and working on other Windows 10 systems without a problem. However, when we open it on this new system, we are getting the following error right away:

Compile error. in query expression 'IIf(Hour(Time())<12,"Good Morning",IIf(Hour(Time())>11 And Hour(Time())<18,"Good Afternoon","Good Evening")'

Removing this query does nothing but bring up additional compile errors.

All of the other computers were running Office Pro 2007 at some point - probably when the database was converted from an .MDB to an .accdb file. They are now running the latest version of Access without issue. They all also have an Inactive Application Add-in called "Microsoft Office 2007 Access Database Engine Conflict Resolver" installed and set to Load on Demand. I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

I did install Office 2007 to this computer (Access module only) and that same add-on then appeared in the newer Access. But I have since uninstalled Office 2007 after the issue remained unresolved. (That add-on is now gone.)

My (probably ignorant) guess is that there is old code that isn't being processed correctly and the current batch of computers are handling it via something that was installed during the upgrade process? Our database needs are pretty simple and there are very few users.

Any help in getting this new system into the loop would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Argh. I think the issue was that I installed the 64-bit version of Office 365. All works now under 32-bit. Sorry and thanks.